# Non-unicity of a limit (of function)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

Today in class our professor mentioned something, while speaking about unicity of a limit for a funciton (or a sequence), about the fact that there are "occasions" in which the limit is not (or cannot?) be unique.

Unfortunately, that was his "outtro" speech, for the lecture was over already, and I couldn't understand well what he said (nor my friends actually). So I tried to do some research over here, but I actually found nothing.

So my question is:

- Is it possible that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exist but it's not unique? In what sense? Under what circumstances?

I really clearly heard, from our professor, he said something about "a real line with two zeroes" (if I understood well), but there was too much noise around...

Thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: It depend on the topology ! This will not happen on a metric space. However, if you take a sequence $(x_n)^{\mathbb R}$ where $\mathbb R$ is endowed with the coarse topology, then $x_n$ wil converges to all points of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer which someone might perhaps expand (?).

In Topology we have the so called Hausdorff spaces which do possess the property by which we can put two different points into two different (open) sets $U, V$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$.
We usually work with Hausdorff spaces for they are good enough for what we need.

If you have a function or a sequence and this does converge to a point, then in the end the sequence or the function will approach to any neighbourhood of that point. For example:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x} = 0^+$$

"Sooner or later" (at the infinity :D) we will arrive at $0^+$, but in the meanwhile we are approaching it in a very close manner, more and more. So any open ball like $B_{\epsilon}(0)$, which represents an open set of radius $\epsilon$ (infinitesimal) centered at zero, will for sure contain the evaluation of $f(x) = e^{-x}$ for large enough $x$. It will nay contain *every* evaluation of the limit of that sequence/function.

For the moment we hence have been working in metric spaces, which are nice spaces and Hausdorff spaces too. In metric spaces we do have, indeed, a metric, hence we can define distances between points, and the prove of the unicity and existence of the above limit relies on some famous $\epsilon-\delta$ proof which you might have been meeting whilst speaking of limits (or you're starting to meet).

We can however think of some space which is not a Hausdorff space, and here things could really get tricky, shady and upside-down. Topsy turvy, innit?
We can indeed have limits which do converge to more than one value/point, and as your professor did mention, the real line with two zeroes is a good starting example: any open set that includes one of those zeroes, must hence include the other too so you can see by yourself that while approaching closer and closer to one you are approaching closer and closer to the other one too.

More here: [Line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that this statement, that a limit is not unique, is hard to imagine when thinking of functions, as it is more a property of the space your sequence (of possible function values) lives in.

Consider for example the topological space $\mathbb{R}\cup\left\lbrace\star\right\rbrace$ equipped with the topology generated by the usual open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ together with all sets of the form $\left(-\epsilon,0\right)\cup\left\lbrace\star\right\rbrace\cup\left(0,\epsilon\right)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. This topological space is not Hausdorff, as $0$ and $\star$ can not be separated by two disjoint open neighborhoods. Furthermore, if a sequence converges to $0$ in this space, but admits no subsequence that becomes constant $0$ (i.e. only contains a finite amount of $0$'s as Daniel Schepller pointed out), it automatically also converges to $\star$. Thus for example for the function
$$\begin{array}{rcl}f:\mathbb{R}&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}\cup\left\lbrace\star\right\rbrace\\x&\mapsto&x\end{array}$$
we have
$$\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\text{lim}}\ f(x)=0\text{ and }\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\text{lim}}\ f(x)=\star$$

Comment: Yes thats true ofcourse. I meant that no subsequence becomes constant 0, not only the sequence itself! I corrected it. Was kind off a drive-by-answer ;)